# NoClassDefFoundError for joda DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, scala, sbt, jodatime, apache-spark

I am trying to use joda's DateTimeFormat in a Spark project (in Scala) for which I am using sbt as a build tool, and it is giving me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I try to run it as a standalone application. This seems odd to me because I don't get any errors when I play with it in the console, but when I try to run it as an application, it errors with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
    at com.bdcoe.poc.spark.analytics.Driver$.main(Driver.scala:35)
    at com.bdcoe.poc.spark.analytics.Driver.main(Driver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 9 more
```

Here is my build.sbt file, which is located in the project's root directory:

```
import AssemblyKeys._
import net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

organization := "com.bdcoe.poc"

name := "spark-analytics"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Local Maven" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val slf4jVersion = "1.7.7"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0",
    "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.2.0",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0" % "test",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % slf4jVersion % "provided",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % slf4jVersion % "test",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.2", 
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.2"
  )
}
```

And here is my import/usage of joda:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.{ forPattern => formatFor }

val dateTime = formatFor("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm").parseDateTime _ 
val timeStamp: DateTime = dateTime(args(2))
```

Any suggestions on why it can find joda in the sbt console but not when run as a standalone application?

Comment: how do you package it? what SBT command or plugin do you use to package it? Do you run the class directly instead of a jar? Can you provide a cmd that you use to run it?

Comment: use java 8 version. java 7 have not containing this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the classpath during runtime.

I've noticed you are using `sbt-assembly`. Add this `assemblySettings` line after imports in your `build.sbt`:

```
import AssemblyKeys._
import net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

assemblySettings

organization := "com.bdcoe.poc"

...
```

as described in the docs: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly. Sbt-assembly will find the main class and package the JAR with a properly configured manifest.

Note that the task you should run is `assembly`, not `package`. Without `assemblySettings` included in your project you would not be able to run this task previously, and since you were running your packaged JAR (most likely) then you've must have generated it with `package` task, and not with `assembly`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange for the JAR file that contains the org.joda classes to be in the CLASSPATH while running.   The console has done this for you, it finds the class and everything runs.  You problem is that when running on the command line, the system is not finding the JAR with the class in it, and is not able to load the class.